# TextContent does not work on my computer

Tags: machine-learning, text, version-12

TextContents does not work, returns

> `TextContents::wlnetcorr2: A required WLNet file is corrupted and could not be loaded.
>
> `TextContents::nlpnetmodel: An internal error occurred while loading a neural net needed to evaluate the function. Please try again.

repeatedly. How to fix it?
(Windows 10, Mathematica 12.0)

Comment: I can confirm this on Mac OS 10.14.4. with Mathematica 12. Tried the example from documentation, got the same error messages

Comment: Have you asked WRI Support?

Comment: Considering that bugs are now discussed and logged on stackexchange, WRI Support should move to stackexchange as well. I really prefer a public catalog or forum for bugs.